# Call to a member function fetch() on boolean on line 26

Tags: php

Can you please suggest what shall i do.

```
// 7. Obtain the unique ID for the newly created entry

$id_obj = $db->query('SELECT_LAST_INSERT_ID()');
$id     = $id_obj->fetch();
$id_obj->closeCursor();
```

Had already seen other two answers here before posting.There is no specific solution and my problem is different.

Comment: Had already seen those two answers before posting.There is no specific solution and my problem is different.

Comment: Your problem is not different. Your query failed and `$id_obj` is `false` as a result. One of the answers on the duplicate question even tells you how to get the relevant error message.